# php's array_multisort function equivalent in java

Tags: java, php, arrays

I was looking for an equivalent of [***php's array_multisort***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) in java.

```
//array 1
ar1 = array(10, 100, 100, 0);
//array 2
ar2 = array(1, 3, 2, 4);
//calling the function
//this will sort the array at first based one the first array and then based on the    
//second array so these two array are related
array_multisort(ar1, ar2);


//resultant 1st array
array(4) {
[0]=> int(0)
[1]=> int(10)
[2]=> int(100)
[3]=> int(100)  
}

//resultant 2nd array
//this array has been sorted based on the first array at first

array(4) {
[0]=> int(4) // this is associative element of 0 in the first array 
[1]=> int(1) //this is associative element of 10 in the first array 
[2]=> int(2) //this is associative element of  1st 100 from the last in the first array 
             //as there are two 100's , and last one's associative value in the second
             //array is smaller it will come first   
[3]=> int(3)
}
```

how can i achieve this result using ***something built-in*** , i know how to implement it using ***custom code***.

N.B. ***Please visit** *this link* **before answering the question as that explains how the function should work***

Comment: you are pointing sort multiple array using built in function not to sort one array

Comment: in java there is no built method to sort two dimesion array . only implement comparing logic

Comment: @MohammodHossain You can edit your previous comment (within 5 minutes) instead of adding a new one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like that there is not any built-in library function / class for this purpose in Java .
If you are also facing this problem like me , so far [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12142998/1426743) about the custom code can help you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit more complicated and can't be done without the Java standard API. So I have recycled a quicksort implementation and made it work for multiple arrays. Basically it swaps the elements when they are swapped by the partitioning of quicksort.

Here you go:

```
 /**
   * Multi-sorts the given arrays with the quicksort algorithm. It assumes that
   * all arrays have the same sizes and it sorts on the first dimension of these
   * arrays. If the given arrays are null or empty, it will do nothing, if just
   * a single array was passed it will sort it via {@link Arrays} sort;
   */
  public static void multiQuickSort(int[]... arrays) {
    multiQuickSort(0, arrays);
  }

  /**
   * Multi-sorts the given arrays with the quicksort algorithm. It assumes that
   * all arrays have the same sizes and it sorts on the given dimension index
   * (starts with 0) of these arrays. If the given arrays are null or empty, it
   * will do nothing, if just a single array was passed it will sort it via
   * {@link Arrays} sort;
   */
  public static void multiQuickSort(int sortDimension, int[]... arrays) {
    // check if the lengths are equal, break if everything is empty
    if (arrays == null || arrays.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // if the array only has a single dimension, sort it and return
    if (arrays.length == 1) {
      Arrays.sort(arrays[0]);
      return;
    }
    // also return if the sort dimension is not in our array range
    if (sortDimension < 0 || sortDimension >= arrays.length) {
      return;
    }
    // check sizes
    int firstArrayLength = arrays[0].length;
    for (int i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++) {
      if (arrays[i] == null || firstArrayLength != arrays[i].length)
        return;
    }

    multiQuickSort(arrays, 0, firstArrayLength, sortDimension);
  }

  /**
   * Internal multi quicksort, doing the real algorithm.
   */
  private static void multiQuickSort(int[][] a, int offset, int length,
      int indexToSort) {
    if (offset < length) {
      int pivot = multiPartition(a, offset, length, indexToSort);
      multiQuickSort(a, offset, pivot, indexToSort);
      multiQuickSort(a, pivot + 1, length, indexToSort);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Partitions the given array in-place and uses the end element as pivot,
   * everything less than the pivot will be placed left and everything greater
   * will be placed right of the pivot. It returns the index of the pivot
   * element after partitioning. This is a multi way partitioning algorithm, you
   * have to provide a partition array index to know which is the array that
   * needs to be partitioned. The swap operations are applied on the other
   * elements as well.
   */
  private static int multiPartition(int[][] array, int start, int end,
      int partitionArrayIndex) {
    final int ending = end - 1;
    final int x = array[partitionArrayIndex][ending];
    int i = start - 1;
    for (int j = start; j < ending; j++) {
      if (array[partitionArrayIndex][j] <= x) {
        i++;
        for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < array.length; arrayIndex++) {
          swap(array[arrayIndex], i, j);
        }
      }
    }
    i++;
    for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < array.length; arrayIndex++) {
      swap(array[arrayIndex], i, ending);
    }

    return i;
  }
 /**
   * Swaps the given indices x with y in the array.
   */
  public static void swap(int[] array, int x, int y) {
    int tmpIndex = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = tmpIndex;
  }
```

Done a little testcase to test your input from the question:

```
@Test
  public void testMultiQuickSort() {
    int[] first = new int[] { 10, 100, 100, 0 };
    int[] second = new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 4 };
    int[] resFirst = new int[] { 0, 10, 100, 100 };
    int[] resSecond = new int[] { 4, 1, 2, 3 };

    ArrayUtils.multiQuickSort(first, second);

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
      assertEquals(resFirst[i], first[i]);
      assertEquals(resSecond[i], second[i]);
    }
  }
```

Seems to work ;)

BTW if you need it for an arbitrary object type, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

<s>A multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays, so iterate over the individual arrays and sort them:</s>

```
int[][] marr = // your multi-dimensional array here
for (int[] arr : marr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
}
```

And if, for whatever possible reason, you only want to sort the first array in the second dimension, this will do:

```
Arrays.sort(marr[0]);
```

Argh, now I understand what you want. If your elements (at least those of the first array) are unique, you can do it via a SortedMap:

```
if(arr1.length!=arr2.length)throw new IllegalArgumentException();
SortedMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    map.put(arr1[i],arr2[i]);
}
int ct = 0;
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    arr1[ct]=entry.getKey();arr2[ct]=entry.getValue();
    ct++;
}
```

Comment: I believe he wants to keep the ordering in the other arrays.

Comment: That's a) a weird requirement and b) a weird reason for a downvote. But whatever...

Comment: He has two separate arrays and wants to sort them both. Not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but he wants to keep the ordering in the other arrays. Plainly said if the algorithm swaps the elements, this operation must also be applied on the other arrays. Look at his example, I think this is pretty clear. And can't be solved with `Arrays.sort()` (well it can, by wrapping the dimensions into an object :p).

Comment: Argh, now I see what this is about. Was blinded by the method name.

Comment: But in his example the key values are not unique: `{ 10, 100, 100, 0 }`.

Comment: @maba yup that is true , but to illustrate my needs that is required. To explain the required actions when two keys will be same what will be the outcome?  In my example , it will be sorted in respect of the second array in this type of situation.

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob go with Thomas' answer

Answer (score -1):

implements Comparator or using algorithm bubble sort

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray); it will sort only one array
```

Comment: Arrays.sort() only sort one dimension array

Comment: I know how to sort an array , i am trying to find an equivalent built in function like array_multisort of php.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe the following code will help you.

You should use `Arrays.sort()`

#### Example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

String [] stringArray = {"ab", "aB", "c", "0", "2", "1Ad", "a10"};

//order Ascending
Arrays.sort(stringArray);

//Descending
Arrays.sort(stringArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: you are sorting one dimension array. but he is asking to sort more than one array

Comment: @bill please visit  [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). This will help you understand what i am looking for.